# Use AutoCommit with UserTransaction together

Tags: java, sql, transactions, database-connection

Would like to know whether below is correct or not?

```
UserTransaction ut = getUserTransaction();
ut.begin();     
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
// perform statement query udpate here

// do i need to call conn.commit? or ut.commit will handle it implicitly?
ut.commit();
```

I saw the code snippet in one of my company's project, I tested it and found some weird behavior, so I am not sure, should we explicitly call `conn.commit()`? or leave the `ut.commit()` handle all the transaction inside itself?

So it started to confuse me what we are supposed to put inside the `UserTransaction.begin()` and `UserTransaction.commit()`? Since it should be mostly SQL statement execution code inside, is it necessary to include `conn = dataSource.getConnection();` inside the block as well? so all the `statement` that generated by the specific `connection` will behave implicitly like we use `AutoCommit(false)`? What happen if we declare the that (`conn = dataSource.getConnection()`) outside of block? Will transaction-handling still working?

Anyone please share some knowledge on how `UserTransaction` work? I basically know how to use it, but no concrete idea what should I take note when I am using it.

Comment: Are you using container or bean managed transactions?

Comment: This is a J2EE web application. Should be J2EE container?

Comment: Well I'd definitely use CMT, but since you're accessing `UserTransaction`, it would imply that you're using BMT. Show the full code of the method (including annotations).

Comment: What is the method doing anyway? Why does it need to start a transaction? In any case I suspect the proper way would be with a `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction attribute instead of trying to hand code that stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Enterprise beans that use container-managed transaction demarcation
>   must not use any transaction-management methods that interfere with
>   the container’s transaction demarcation boundaries. Examples of such
>   methods are the commit, setAutoCommit, and rollback methods of
>   java.sql.Connection or the commit and rollback methods of
>   javax.jms.Session. If you require control over the transaction
>   demarcation, you must use application-managed transaction demarcation.
>
> Enterprise beans that use container-managed transaction demarcation
>   also must not use the javax.transaction.UserTransaction interface.

I have read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html) , I think probably it is not very good idea to use Transaction and the `autoCommit` at the same time.